# JQuery Validation Plugin Question

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have seen several other posts with similar questions but nothing exactly like what I need to do. I need to have three checkboxes all with the same name but different ID's. When checkbox one is clicked then either 2 or 3 (either one) are required. But if the first checkbox is not clicked then none are required. This is the closest example of what I saw but not 100% there:

[jquery validation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330573/jquery-validation-rules)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you answered your own question, you should put the answer below in an actual answer and then accept it. Otherwise, people will be confused and still think you need help.

Comment: Thanks Michael, updated with answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Well I was extremely over thinking this. At least two were always supposed to be required so this simple statement was all I needed:

{ required: true, minlength:2 }

Which I found here:

jQuery validate plugin with a minimum of 2 elements from a single array name

And then just added my message:

```
messages: {
    fieldname: {
        required:"Must select at least two of the three below options",
        minlength: jQuery.format("Must select at least two of the three below options")
    }
```