# conditional jquery validation based on radio value in form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using validation plugin. 
I want to validate certain fields IN THE SAME form, when radio value is other than "REGULAR",

```
<form id="registerform">
<input type="radio" name="role" value="REGULAR" checked="checked" id="role">Regular<br />
<input type="radio" name="role" value="AGENT" id="role">Agent<br />
<input type="radio" name="role" value="ORGANIZATION" id="role">Organization<br />

<input type="text" name="phone"  id="phone"><br/>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password"><br/>

<input type="text" name="work_area" id="work_area" value=""><br/>
<input type="text" name="work_phone" id="work_phone" value=""><br/>

<input type="text" name="org_name" id="org_name"><br/>
<input type="text" name="org_phone" id="org_phone"><br/>
</form>
```

When role == "REGULAR", validate phone, password 
When role == "AGENT", validate phone, password, **work_area, work_phone** 
When role == "ORGANIZATION", validate phone, password, **org_name, org_phone**
How to achieve this elegantly ? 
I don't want to divide it into different forms!

My false code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var rule_options = 
{
    "phone": "required"
    ,"password": "required"
};

var role = $("#registerform").find("input[name=role]:checked").val();
if(role ==  "AGENT") {
    $.extend(true, rule_options, 
        {
            "work_area": "required"
            ,"work_phone": "required"
        }
    );
}

if(role ==  "ORGANIZATION") {
    $.extend(true, rule_options, 
        {
            "org_area": "required"
            ,"org_phone": "required"
        }
    );
}
jform.validate({
            errorClass : "err_label",
            rules: rule_options,
            ignore: "",
```

Above code won't work since its run only once after document.ready. 
I must be missing something, some syntax..~ Idea ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[jquery validation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330573/jquery-validation-rules/1330616#1330616)

I got what I really needed from above link. What need to be solved here really is how to make the jQuery validator plugin behave **DYNAMICALLY** BASED on radio value for each input. I don't even use jQuery.change() method.

```
function getRole() {
    return $("#registerform").find("input[name=role]:checked").val();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var jform = $("#registerform");
    jform.validate({
            errorClass : "err_label",
            rules: 
                "phone": "required"
                ,"password": "required"
                ,"work_area": {
                    required: function(element) {
                        return (getRole() == 'AGENT');
                    }
                }
                ,"work_phone": {
                    required: function(element) {
                        return (getRole() == 'AGENT');
                    }
                }
                ,"org_name": {
                    required: function(element) {
                        return (getRole() == 'ORGANIZATION');
                    }
                }
                ,"org_phone": {
                    required: function(element) {
                        return (getRole() == 'ORGANIZATION');
                    }
                }
```

If exist other idea, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, this is something like how I would have answered your question.

Comment: after viewing your profile, I just realized that there exist tag "jquery-validate". Is the tag meant for jQuery validation plugin ? I should have use the tag in my question. Thx ~

Comment: Yes,  `[jquery-validate]` is for the jQuery Validate plugin and a proper tag for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use ignore option. Sorry if there is any syntax error as I don't have access to my development tools and jsfiddle is not working from my computer.

EDIT: I am assuming all fields are required.

```
$("form").validate({ignore: ".ignore"});

var role = {
    "REGULAR": ["work_area", "work_phone", "org_name", "org_phone"],
    "AGENT": ["org_name", "org_phone"],
    "ORGANIZATION": ["org_name", "org_phone"]
};

$("input[name=role]").click(function () {
    //reset ignore
    $("#work_area,#work_phone,#org_name,#org_phone").removeClass("ignore");

    for (var i in role[$(this).val()])
    {
        $(i).addClass("ignore");
    }
});
```

Comment: I got the point. But.. using the "negation logic" seems will be confusing and hard to maintain the code. Actually the fields is much more more than I typed. Thanks anyway.~

Comment: If you don't want to use the built-in functionality, you'll have to write your own custom jquery.validate rule.

Comment: This answer is very verbose.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("input[@name='role']").change(function(){
    // Rest of your code here.
});
```

Insted of using the onload event, bind the function to the radiobuttons.

Answer (score -1):

You can update the validation rules, every time the user clicks on the form or presses a key on it.

```
function updateRules() {
  // Your code here
}

$('#registerform').click(function() {
  updateRules();
});

$('#registerform').keyUp(function() {
  updateRules();
});
```

Comment: how to update rules ? Using validator plugin, do I need to resetForm() and rewrite the whole jform.validate() in updateRules() function ?

Comment: You dynamically update the rules using [the `rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).  This critical piece should not have been left out of this answer.

Comment: @Sparky Thx, the rules('add') seems work on a single input. How about if I want to reset the validator and throw/update a new rules set for several inputs at once ? Does the plugin let me do this ?

Comment: @HendryH. ,  yes, it's just a matter of the proper jQuery selectors combined with an `each()`.  Search my answers for several examples.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are doing:

```
var role = $("#registerform").find("input[name=role]:checked").val();
```

and its working, but only once since you need to attach this to an event (maybe the change event is suitable), so every time the radiobuttons somehow changes, the validation setting should change:

```
$("input[@name='role']").change(function(){
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ){ // check if the radio is checked
        var val = $(this).val(); // retrieve the value
        if(role ==  "AGENT") {
           $.extend(true, rule_options, {
              "work_area": "required"
             ,"work_phone": "required"});
        }
        if(role ==  "ORGANIZATION") {
           $.extend(true, rule_options, {
              "org_area": "required"
             ,"org_phone": "required"});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: yes that solve the dynamic part. I'm more of confused of 'how to update the validator' using the correct syntax.

Comment: @HendryH. what's the problem with update the `rule_options` array?

Comment: Its just work fine. Solve half of my problem. But, I don't know how to let my "created validator" to apply to the new rule_options.

Comment: @HendryH. That's not the question, but which plugin are you using and when you want to validate the form (when user change the radio or before the form is submitted)

Comment: I'm using jQuery validation plugin. Sorry for not pointing this out. I thought this plugin is jquery standard. lol.